# Disabling ssh port forwarding set in .ssh/config

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

I have port forwarding enabled by default in my `.ssh/config` for one machine:

```
Host machine
    LocalForward 8888 127.0.0.1:8889
```

Now, I would like to use the command line to ssh to that machine, but with port forwarding disabled (in specific cases). Is it possible to override the config file setting with a command line option of `ssh`?

Comment: [Duplicate on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/826736/how-to-temporarily-disable-local-forwards/826740#826740).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `ClearAllForwardings` option:

```
ssh -o ClearAllForwardings=yes machine
```

From [`ssh_config(5)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5)

> `ClearAllForwardings`
>                Specifies that all local, remote, and dynamic port forwardings specified in the configuration files or on the command line
>                be cleared.  This option is primarily useful when used from the ssh(1) command line to clear port forwardings set in configuration files, and is automatically set by `scp(1)` and `sftp(1)`.  The argument must be "yes" or "no".  The default is
>                "no".